# Problem with battery indicator in Lubuntu 15.04

Tags: lubuntu, indicator, 15.04

I have a Toshiba NB300 with a 1GB RAM and the latest version 15.04 of Lubuntu didn't show up the battery icon.

How can I resolve it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug with lubuntu vivid in bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-power-manager/+bug/1446247

That it does not show in the panel but there is another indicator with right clicking on the panel panel settings click on the panel applets tab  click the add button and add battery monitor is the easiest workaround. If you don't want to right click on the panel you can also use `lxpanelctl config`. Then add the panel applet. It should show your battery.

If you launch xfce4 power manager from the menu you can also see the charge but this could be a little less convenient.

Answer (score 2):

Install 1.5.0 version of `xfce4-power-manager`, `xfce4-power-manager-data` and `xfce4-power-manager-plugins` from [the launchpad site](https://launchpad.net/~xubuntu-dev/+archive/ubuntu/xubuntu-staging). Open the terminal and;

1. Follow the ppa instructions to correctly add the ppa for 15.04, then run:
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` **Note:** `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` will also upgrade other packages. Be careful.
4. run `xfce4-power-manager-settings` command from the command line and then check that Status notifications and System tray icon are set ON. **Note:** Also check "System Tray" is added on "Panel Applets" on the LXDE panel settings.
5. run `xfce4-power-manager --restart` from the command line
6. run `lxpanelctl restart`

After that you will have the "battery icon" on your lxpanel.

Comment: It didn't works!